# Titan Graph: Group by query for specific vertex

Tags: titan

I have following situation:

```
User (userId,Name)
Group (groupId,groupName,createdTime)

User ------ created -------> Group1
User ------ created -------> Group2
User ------ created -------> Group3
```

I want to get the list of group created by user in desending order. I have this query

```
//g is TitanGraph
g.query().interval("createdTime",0,time).orderBy("createdTime", 
                 Order.DESC).limit(5).vertices();
```

This will traverse whole graph. but i want for the specific user using `userId`

Means i will take `userId` and show all group created by that `userId` sorted by `createdTime`

One I was trying

```
g.query().has(`userId`,'xyz').interval("createdTime",0,time).orderBy("createdTime", 
                 Order.DESC).limit(5).vertices();
```

Din't work.it was just returning nothing.

Comment: Do you want the result for a single `userId` or an aggregated result for each `userId`?

Comment: i will take `userId` and show all group name created by that`userId` sorted by createdTime

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
g.v(userId).outE.interval("createdTime",0,time).orderBy("createdTime", Order.DESC).limit(5);
```

Comment: Can you give it in java code specific to Titan. Because i got it but confused how to do it for titan

Comment: shouldn't the gremlin start with `g.v(userId)` (parens instead of square brackets)?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a Graph Query when you want a Vertex Query:

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Vertex-Centric-Indices

Query the vertex first and then execute the query from there, like:

```
Vertex v = g.getVertex(userId)
v.query().has(`userId`,'xyz').interval("createdTime",0,time).orderBy("createdTime", 
                 Order.DESC).limit(5).vertices()
```

I guess this is basically the answer from @MarcoCI written with Titan/Java instead of Gremlin.

Comment: I knew this but the thing is `VertexQuery` doensn't have `OrderBy` method.Its `TitanGraphQuery` that has method `OrderBy`. and you can get `TitanGraphQuery` from `TitanGraph` only. `IdGraph` doesn't have any OrderBy support. Here I am talking about `IdGraph` cos `g.getVeretx(userId)` will only run in `IdGraph` cos `userId` is custom id given to vertex by me and `TitanGraph` doen't support that. So basically the thing is I will have to use IdGraph to get a particular vertex by its Id and so I wont get OrderBy query method.Right?

Comment: Got the solution for the same question here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/n0AyWioVnoY